# Image & CSS doesn't display Middleman + Github Pages

Tags: github, middleman

I'm new to web development and am trying to get my website live on Github pages. I'm using the middleman-deploy gem. When I go to my site: http://rachaelsalter.github.io/rsblog/ the css and background image does not load. Hoping someone can help. Thanks.

https://github.com/rachaelsalter/rsblog

Answer (score 0):

As your deployed site is not served at the root of your github subdomain (rachaelsalter.github.io), you need to instruct middleman to make assets links relative to `/rsblog` for your deployable builds.

```
configure :build do
   set :http_prefix, "/rsblog"
end
```

Comment: David, I'm having the same problem (images and svg doesn't work) but my installation is at the root (I don't know if it's allowed to post a link to my ost here). Do you have any idea? :/

Comment: You better post a new question.

Comment: David, I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846634/middleman-not-found-error-file-shows-in-sitemap :)