# Middleman Not Found Error (File shows in Sitemap)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I removed the old post and I decided to better clarify the problems.

1. I moved the images from /**img**/ directory to /**images**/, then I removed the /img/ directory and updated all html.erb and partials files to point to /images/ instead of /img/.
2. I installed **bootstrap** (manually, I had some problems with bower so I decided to do "the easy way").

Then I decided to run "bundle exec middleman build --verbose --clean". As you can see, the command execute normally, but there is a "not found" error in .svg bootstrap font. The font shows in sitemap.

The images don't shows error but when I access in the sitemap, shows a "not found" error.

```
PS C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.25-0\apache2\htdocs\geteloquent.github.io> bundle exec middleman build --verbose --clean
== Activating: sprockets
== Reading:  Local config
== Activating: directory_indexes
Loaded extensions:
== Extension: sprockets
== Extension: directory_indexes
== Extension: frontmatter
== File Change: config.rb
== File Change: README.md
== File Change: source/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22037a34.woff
== File Change: source/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-3ef91859.svg
== File Change: source/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-aafafdc0.ttf
== File Change: source/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-f3a9a3b6.eot
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Black Italic.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Black.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Bold Italic.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Bold.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Light Italic.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Light.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Regular Italic.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Regular.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Thin Italic.otf
== File Change: source/fonts/Mission Gothic Thin.otf
== File Change: source/images/background.png
== File Change: source/images/hero-backdrop-3e7a3371.png
== File Change: source/images/hero-link-cac0a934.png
== File Change: source/images/juliana-821176d0.jpg
== File Change: source/images/left-c05ff2c8.png
== File Change: source/images/logo-hero-b3ca0c15.png
== File Change: source/images/logo-navbar-9ac7651b.png
== File Change: source/images/middleman.png
== File Change: source/images/phone-preview-smallest-df69b30d.png
== File Change: source/images/right-d9a6ebde.png
== File Change: source/images/service-dds-e75cbb0e.png
== File Change: source/images/service-enterprise-5be62e73.png
== File Change: source/images/services-background-f4635b43.png
== File Change: source/images/sn-facebook-47838955.png
== File Change: source/images/sn-github-bc0645b2.png
== File Change: source/images/sn-twitter-739983f2.png
== File Change: source/index.html.erb
== File Change: source/javascripts/all.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js
== File Change: source/javascripts/jquery.js
== File Change: source/layouts/layout.erb
== File Change: source/partials/_footer.erb
== File Change: source/partials/_nav.erb
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/3994c8c2a99deec462fe394bba54fc5fdb72a113/main.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/3994c8c2a99deec462fe394bba54fc5fdb72a113/_bootstrap.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/3994c8c2a99deec462fe394bba54fc5fdb72a113/_fonts.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/3994c8c2a99deec462fe394bba54fc5fdb72a113/_theme.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_alerts.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_background-variant.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_border-radius.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_buttons.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_center-block.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_clearfix.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_forms.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_gradients.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_grid-framework.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_grid.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_hide-text.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_image.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_labels.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_list-group.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_nav-divider.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_nav-vertical-align.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_opacity.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_pagination.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_panels.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_progress-bar.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_reset-filter.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_reset-text.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_resize.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_responsive-visibility.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_size.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_tab-focus.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_table-row.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_text-emphasis.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_text-overflow.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/71990890f83decde0d2761ffd30ec475634e0fa0/_vendor-prefixes.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_alerts.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_badges.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_breadcrumbs.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_button-groups.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_buttons.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_carousel.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_close.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_code.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_component-animations.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_dropdowns.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_forms.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_glyphicons.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_grid.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_input-groups.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_jumbotron.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_labels.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_list-group.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_media.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_mixins.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_modals.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_navbar.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_navs.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_normalize.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_pager.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_pagination.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_panels.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_popovers.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_print.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_progress-bars.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_responsive-embed.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_responsive-utilities.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_scaffolding.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_tables.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_thumbnails.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_tooltip.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_type.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_utilities.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_variables.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/.sass-cache/c067f657988d7ba69e474cad1850294ea3e59484/_wells.scssc
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_alerts.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_background-variant.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_border-radius.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_center-block.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_clearfix.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_forms.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_gradients.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_grid.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_hide-text.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_image.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_labels.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_list-group.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_nav-divider.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_nav-vertical-align.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_opacity.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_pagination.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_panels.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_progress-bar.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_reset-filter.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_reset-text.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_resize.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_responsive-visibility.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_size.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_tab-focus.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_table-row.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_text-overflow.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_alerts.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_badges.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_breadcrumbs.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_button-groups.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_buttons.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_carousel.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_close.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_code.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_component-animations.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_dropdowns.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_forms.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_glyphicons.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_grid.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_input-groups.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_jumbotron.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_labels.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_list-group.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_media.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_mixins.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_modals.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navbar.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navs.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_normalize.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_pager.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_pagination.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_panels.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_popovers.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_print.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_progress-bars.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-embed.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-utilities.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_scaffolding.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_tables.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_theme.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_thumbnails.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_tooltip.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_type.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_utilities.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/bootstrap/_wells.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/main.css
== File Change: source/stylesheets/main.css.map
== File Change: source/stylesheets/main.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_bootstrap-compass.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_bootstrap-mincer.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_bootstrap-sprockets.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_fonts.scss
== File Change: source/stylesheets/_theme.scss
== Rebuilding resource list
== Prerendering CSS
   identical  build/stylesheets/main.css
   identical  build/stylesheets/main.css
== Checking for Compass sprites
== Building files
   identical  build/images/service-enterprise-5be62e73.png
   identical  build/images/hero-link-cac0a934.png
   identical  build/images/sn-twitter-739983f2.png
   identical  build/images/sn-github-bc0645b2.png
   identical  build/images/sn-facebook-47838955.png
   identical  build/images/services-background-f4635b43.png
   identical  build/images/service-dds-e75cbb0e.png
   identical  build/images/right-d9a6ebde.png
   identical  build/images/background.png
   identical  build/images/middleman.png
   identical  build/images/logo-navbar-9ac7651b.png
   identical  build/images/logo-hero-b3ca0c15.png
   identical  build/images/left-c05ff2c8.png
   identical  build/images/hero-backdrop-3e7a3371.png
   identical  build/images/phone-preview-smallest-df69b30d.png
   identical  build/images/juliana-821176d0.jpg
       error  build/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-3ef91859.svg
Not found
   identical  build/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-22037a34.woff
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Thin Italic.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Regular.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Regular Italic.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Light.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Light Italic.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Bold.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Black Italic.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Thin.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Black.otf
   identical  build/fonts/Mission Gothic Bold Italic.otf
   identical  build/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-aafafdc0.ttf
   identical  build/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular-f3a9a3b6.eot
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js
   identical  build/javascripts/all.js
   identical  build/javascripts/jquery.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap.js
   identical  build/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js
   identical  build/stylesheets/main.css.map
== Request: /index.html
== Finishing Request: index.html (0.02s)
   identical  build/index.html
There were errors during this build
```

You can check the files at the directory:
https://github.com/yeltsin/geteloquent.github.io

Or here:

**config.rb**

```
compass_config do |config|
  config.output_style = :compact
end

set :css_dir, 'stylesheets'
set :js_dir, 'javascripts'
set :images_dir, 'images'
set :partials_dir, 'partials'
set :fonts_dir, 'fonts'

activate :directory_indexes

configure :development do
  activate :livereload
end

configure :build do
  activate :minify_css
  activate :minify_javascript
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
# If you do not have OpenSSL installed, update
# the following line to use "http://" instead
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "middleman", "~>3.3.12"
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

# Custom Middleman Extensions
gem "middleman-blog"
gem "middleman-livereload", "~> 3.1.0"

# For faster file watcher updates on Windows:
gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.0", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]

# Windows does not come with time zone data
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: [:mswin, :mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionpack (4.1.12)
      actionview (= 4.1.12)
      activesupport (= 4.1.12)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.12)
      activesupport (= 4.1.12)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activesupport (4.1.12)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    builder (3.2.2)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    chunky_png (1.3.4)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    compass (1.0.3)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      compass-core (~> 1.0.2)
      compass-import-once (~> 1.0.5)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
      sass (>= 3.3.13, < 3.5)
    compass-core (1.0.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      sass (>= 3.3.0, < 3.5)
    compass-import-once (1.0.5)
      sass (>= 3.2, < 3.5)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.7)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    ffi (1.9.10-x86-mingw32)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2-x86-mingw32)
    hooks (0.4.0)
      uber (~> 0.0.4)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    kramdown (1.8.0)
    listen (2.10.1)
      celluloid (~> 0.16.0)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    middleman (3.3.12)
      coffee-script (~> 2.2)
      compass (>= 1.0.0, < 2.0.0)
      compass-import-once (= 1.0.5)
      execjs (~> 2.0)
      haml (>= 4.0.5)
      kramdown (~> 1.2)
      middleman-core (= 3.3.12)
      middleman-sprockets (>= 3.1.2)
      sass (>= 3.4.0, < 4.0)
      uglifier (~> 2.5)
    middleman-blog (3.5.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3.5)
      middleman-core (~> 3.2)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.0)
    middleman-core (3.3.12)
      activesupport (~> 4.1.0)
      bundler (~> 1.1)
      erubis
      hooks (~> 0.3)
      i18n (~> 0.7.0)
      listen (>= 2.7.9, < 3.0)
      padrino-helpers (~> 0.12.3)
      rack (>= 1.4.5, < 2.0)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      thor (>= 0.15.2, < 2.0)
      tilt (~> 1.4.1, < 2.0)
    middleman-livereload (3.1.1)
      em-websocket (>= 0.2.0)
      middleman-core (>= 3.0.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack-livereload
    middleman-sprockets (3.4.2)
      middleman-core (>= 3.3)
      sprockets (~> 2.12.1)
      sprockets-helpers (~> 1.1.0)
      sprockets-sass (~> 1.3.0)
    minitest (5.7.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    padrino-helpers (0.12.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.7)
      padrino-support (= 0.12.5)
      tilt (~> 1.4.1)
    padrino-support (0.12.5)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-livereload (0.3.16)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    railties (4.1.12)
      actionpack (= 4.1.12)
      activesupport (= 4.1.12)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.5)
    rb-inotify (0.9.5)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    sass (3.4.16)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-helpers (1.1.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sprockets-sass (1.3.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.5)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uber (0.0.13)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    wdm (0.1.1)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  middleman (~> 3.3.12)
  middleman-blog
  middleman-livereload (~> 3.1.0)
  sass-rails (>= 3.2)
  tzinfo-data
  wdm (~> 0.1.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both error 1 and error 2 was due filename. For some reasons Middleman can get confused if there is numbers and letters after the name of the file.